# Wordpress getID add active class

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, getid3

i have a Wordpress page called Jobs (https://www.bap.cc/jobs/).
There i want to display two different posttypes (Jobs & Jobsangbote).

Everything works well, except the active function in my php. The first block “Wir suchen“ is okay, “Wir bieten“ active function doesn't work. Don't know why...

```
    <?php

    get_header(); ?>

    <div class="overflow-y ios blur"><article class="article barba-        container"><div id="agenturtext" class="text overflow firefox">
<?php
    // Start the loop.
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<header>';
    the_title('<h1 id="agenturheader">','</h1>');
    echo '</header>';
    the_content();
        // Include the page content template.
        //get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );


    // End the loop.
    endwhile;
    ?>
    </div>
    <div id="float" class="overflow jobs firefox">
    <div class="agenturbild">
    <?php 
    $id=get_the_ID();
    $thumbnail_id=get_post_thumbnail_id($id);
    $tablet=wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumbnail_id, 'tablet')[0];
    $srcset=wp_get_attachment_image_srcset($thumbnail_id);
    $alt=get_post_meta( $thumbnail_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
    echo '<img src="' . $tablet . '" srcset="' . $srcset . '" alt="' . ($alt?$alt:' ') . '" class="lazyload"></div>' /*sizes="(max-width: 920px) 33vw, (max-width: 1200px) 50vw, (max-width: 1500px) 60vw, (max-width:2000px) 70vw, 80vw"*/; ?>

    <div id="jobmenu">
    <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'jobs', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=>'date', 'order'=>'DESC' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    $a=0;
    if ($loop->found_posts>1){
    echo '
    <div class="jobueberschrift"><h2 class="jobtitel">Wir suchen:</h2></div>';
    $ID=get_the_ID();
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<div><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="joblink' .         (get_the_ID()===$ID?' jobactive':'') . '">';the_title('<h2>','</h2>');echo '</a></div>';
        // Include the page content template.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

    // End the loop.
        endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();

?>
    <?php $argsangebote = array( 'post_type' => 'jobsangebote', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby'=>'date', 'order'=>'DESC' );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $argssangebote );
    $a=0;
    if ($loop->found_posts>1){
    echo '
    <div class="jobueberschrift" style="margin-top:52px !important;">        <h2 class="jobtitel">Wir bieten:</h2></div>';
    $ID=get_the_ID();
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    echo '<div><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" class="joblink' .         (get_the_ID()===$ID?' jobactive':'') . '">';the_title('<h2>','</h2>');echo         '</a></div>';
        // Include the page content template.
        get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );

    // End the loop.
    endwhile;
    }       

?>
</div>

    </article></div>

    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```